# RADIAL Colorramp gradient texture

Tags: texturing

Ok so I got as far as getting the colors I want, and making them gradient. Now my question is how do I get the colors to wrap around a circle mesh like the rings around a planet? Im guessing it has something to do with mapping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## In cycles

use a gradient texture using a quadratic sphere as the color style blending.

### [image]

## Blender Internal

Use quadratic sphere for the blend and sphere for the projection:

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much, I was stumped...

Answer (score 2):

**In Cycles**

A rings texture can be generated using color ramps and object coordinates.

[image: Sphere rings]

This texture was generated using this node setup.

[image: Nodes texture]

The key idea is to use one coordinate axis and a color ramp to cycle through the different bands.

---

For rings about the planet, you can convert the object x-y coordinate into a radius using sqrt(x^2+y^2) and a color ramp.

The geometry is a sphere and filled in circle for the rings.

[image: planet and ring]

The node setup for the texture converts the x-y coordinates into a radius, then uses the radius to lookup the color. Also, alpha can be set in the color ramp to make the rings transparent in spots and near the planet.

[image: nodes setup]

[image: planet with ring]

Adding a transparent color to the color ramp, puts gaps in the rings.

[image]