# Applying roof tilles on cone shaped roof in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking

I have problem with applying roof tile texture on a conical roof in blender. I use this image as a reference

[image]

And when I try to unwrap the cone I got this circular shaped projection which is useless with horizontally aligned tile texture.

[image]

So Is there any other texturing method or any other option to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92812/how-can-i-assign-the-texture-on-saturns-rings or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically

Answer (score 1):

I have not unwrapped anything (successfully) before, but here is an idea. In GIMP, open your image:
[image]

At the top choose filters>distorts>polar-coordinates and set it up as shown:
[image]

It will be easier to map to your cone, and the tiles will point towards the top, but they will be longer towards the bottom I think, so . . . You can try that if you want. :D

[image]