# generated circular UV map

Tags: vector-mapping

I am struggling a bit with uv mapping. i wanted to texture this circle but i get this instead of a perfect circular wood texture... i even tried spherical on color node but it doesnt seem to be the right way!

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92812/how-can-i-assign-an-image-texture-gradient-along-a-circlular-ring

Comment: thank you . your answer worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the side and use the *Unwrap > Cylinder Projection*. As for the front sides, first unwrap, enable the *UV Squares* addon, and click on the *To Grid By Shape* button:

[image]

Result, the texture follows the shape:

[image]

Comment: it worked! thank you so much moonboots