# How to make the color fade in to another one on the same object? (Like Pic below)

Tags: color

[image: The explosion how it is orange on the inside then on the edge it fades to reddish orange.]

The explosion how it is orange on the inside then on the edge it fades to reddish orange

Comment: you would use a color ramp node for that

Comment: answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/radial-colorramp-gradient-texture?noredirect=1

Comment: So duplicate... (@moonboots)