# How to keep the gradient when joining objects?

Tags: materials, node-editor

On the left, the petals are separate (linked) objects.
On the right, they're joined into one object - but the gradient type changed.

How to keep the same gradient type when I join the petals together into a single object?

[image: my node setup]

Comment: You can use a radial gradient, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/radial-colorramp-gradient-texture?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(Edited using the provided file)</sup>

To keep the gradient when joining the petals, you can use *UV coordinates*.
Then just project the UV map from top and join.

[image]

(To get the same UV map, just select the petal and *UV > Project from view*)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm not getting the similar result to my first setup. You solution is similar to the picture below. (see how the gradient align on each object)

---

[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/0fOaErk.png)

---

[Source file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdy7thwtr37awm9/plumeria-01.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Well, you're using Z coordinates to drive the gradient. I suggested a UV map :).

Comment: Well, I already tried that. but treating them as one single object is not getting the result I want. (see my annotation in screenshot above)

Comment: Here is the result using UV --- [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/H7TVBDt.png)

Comment: Hey :). Could you please add an image of your *desired final result*? Maybe I misunderstood :).

Comment: The left one in all above screenshots. Also by using UV it got a bit ugly on the bottom. --- [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/HuKBmwY.png)

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't understand what you don't like :). Project UV map for one petal an then join - the uv map is the same for each petal. https://imgur.com/a/odtS2Vr

Comment: Sorry, XD I'm just new to new to this "node" thing, I'm still learning. My result using UV node like you said, Is not same as your screenshot.

Maybe I'm just done something wrong?

Comment: Hey :). I also modified the UV. The original UV map in your file didn't work that well, so I changed it (projected from top)

Comment: Oh, got it. XD ... I have to do the "project from view" to get same result as your... Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes :). Okay, if you get stuck anywhere, feel free to post a new question. Good luck.